# Postponing ntpd

Tags: init.d, ntpd

I am currently trying to cut boot time for an embedded Linux system. One way we figured we could do that is by postponing the ntp init.d script.

The daemon tried to synchronize with the server via the ethernet connection. But we don't always have that connection up and it takes a long time to boot while it tries to synchronize. In our system, ntp is not crucial, so it can be started in a later time.

What I wanted to do was to make the ntpd init.d script to wait for like 5 minutes but without blocking the rest of the boot operation.

This is the S49 in the init.d folder I'm using:

```sh
    #! /bin/sh
    #
    # System-V init script for the openntp daemon
    #

    PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
    DESC="network time protocol daemon"
    NAME=ntpd
    DAEMON=/usr/sbin/$NAME
    NTPDATE_BIN=/usr/bin/ntpdate

    # Gracefully exit if the package has been removed.
    test -x $DAEMON || exit 0

    # Read config file if it is present.
    if [ -r /etc/default/$NAME ]
    then
        . /etc/default/$NAME
    fi

    case "$1" in
    start)
        if [ -x $NTPDATE_BIN ] ; then
            echo -n "Getting initial time via ntp"
            $NTPDATE_BIN $NTPDATE_OPTS $NTPSERVERS > /dev/null 2>&1
            echo "."
        fi

        echo -n "Starting $DESC: $NAME"
        start-stop-daemon -S -q -x $DAEMON
        echo "."
        ;;
    stop) echo -n "Stopping $DESC: $NAME"
        start-stop-daemon -K -q -n $NAME
        echo "."
        ;;
    reload|force-reload) echo -n "Reloading $DESC configuration..."
        start-stop-daemon -K -q -n $NAME -s 1
        echo "done."
            ;;
    restart) echo "Restarting $DESC: $NAME"
        $0 stop
        sleep 1
        $0 start
        ;;
    *) echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload}" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac

    exit 0
```

Comment: Would you consider an event based init serverice?

Comment: What OS? `ntpd` should be backgrounding itself, and should not hang anything. This isn't some custom init script is it?

Comment: I don't think it's up to me to change the init service. And I'm not sure whether the script is custom or not.

Comment: Ditto Patrick.  Unless you've done some work to create such a situation yourself, the boot process will not stop and wait for ntpd to get a connection.  It will just start the daemon in the background.  So either you need to explain what you've done to make it like that, *or* why you believe that is happening if you didn't.

Comment: @franchzilla Are you starting the ntp daemon, or are you doing a one-time time sync on boot? The one-time sync will pause boot. You could be doing a one-time sync with `ntpdate` or `ntpd -q`

Comment: @franchzilla "I don't think it's up to me to change the init service.". That's exactly what you're asking for. You asked for a way to "make the ntpd init.d script to wait for like 5 minutes". Which is it? You also didn't answer my questions, which are critical for determining where the problem lies.

Comment: @derobert that's why I was asking about if they've modified the script. Doing a manual sync at boot is one of the most common blunders with ntp. Few seem to know that ntpd has this one-time-sync functionality built into it, it just has to be turned on.

Comment: @Patrick Sorry. What I meant is that I can't change the init service to an event based one, such as upstart. I have to keep using the System-V init. But actually, there is a test to check if ntpdate is executable and, if it is, the script runs ntpdate.

Comment: Okay so your OS uses SysV. Could please first state what OS you're using? That might be quite helpful in diagnosing things.

Comment: Edit your question and include the full content of the script starting ntpd

Comment: I added the script, as required. Also, the OS I'm using is linux 2.6.32.2 for a Samsung ARM processor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your init script shows, your delay is being caused by `ntpdate` when it starts.

This is one of the most common errors when setting up NTP. The purpose of using `ntpdate` is so that `ntpd` won't exit with an error when it starts up. It does this if it detects that the time difference is very large. However `ntpd` has the ability to ignore this time difference just once. So by turning this on, `ntpdate` is no longer necessary.

The solution then is to disable `ntpdate` and use this feature.

To do this, all you need to do is create `/etc/default/ntpd` with the following:

```
NTPDATE_BIN="-"
DAEMON="/usr/sbin/ntpd -g"
```

---

The `NTPDATE_BIN="-"` is for this bit of the init script:

```
if [ -x $NTPDATE_BIN ] ; then
```

It will look to see if there is a file called `-` which is executable, which there isn't, so it will skip that section.

The `DAEMON="/usr/sbin/ntpd -g"` is for this:

```
start-stop-daemon -S -q -x $DAEMON
```

It will cause `ntpd` to be invoked as `ntpd -g`. The `-g` option is the option that tells it allow the large time difference.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
case "$1" in
start)
    if [ -x $NTPDATE_BIN ] ; then
        echo -n "Getting initial time via ntp"
        $NTPDATE_BIN $NTPDATE_OPTS $NTPSERVERS > /dev/null 2>&1
        echo "."
    fi
```

ntpdate is getting executed at boot independently of everything if it's found as executable. If you want to stop this behavior you should remove ntpdate using the package manager you have or manually moving the binary.

Modifying the script is also an option, but if you update it's probably that it would get overwritten.

Comment: But is there some way to make ntpdate run after 5 minutes this script is run without blocking the rest of the boot up?

Comment: @franchzilla since you don't want the time to be updated at boot disabling it and leaving the daemon take care of the time sync seems like the wisest approach instead of trying to delaying. Remember that SysV init scripts are extremely limited in functionality. Delaying scripts without blocking the rest when having the exact time at boot time isn't a priority is trying to solve the problem using the wrong approach.